# Can't open a view in Business Activity Monitoring

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-bam

I use BizTalk Server 2010. Yesterday I deployed a BAM activity and could browse a corresponding view in the BAM portal. Today I've created another activity, but this time I made it non-RTA and hence I can't open a view for that. Every browser gives me an error:

```
Views cannot be displayed for one or more of the following reasons: 

- Office Web Components 2003 are not installed.
- Your Web Browser does not support ActiveX controls. 
- Support for ActiveX controls is disabled.
```

I've installed Office Web Components 2003 previously and ActiveX controls are enabled. Where's the problem?

Answer (score 2):

Reinstalling Office Web Components 2003 fixed the issue

Answer (score 0):

If you are using your BizTalk installation for tutorial purpose and you have BAM Portal and IE
installed on same machine then you may encounter this error.
Do the following step to get rid of it:

Go to IE Tools -> Internet Options -> Security -> trusted sites -> Sites -> add your BAM website(`http://localhost`).

(You may need to uncheck -- Require server verification (https:) for all sites in the safe zone)

after that if you need, you may check the option.